# What is the difference between link and Link from svelte-routing and when to use which?

Tags: routes, svelte

In [`svelte-routing`](https://github.com/EmilTholin/svelte-routing) there is the `Link` component (with an uppercase "L") and `link` as an action. From the description:

**Link**:

*A component used to navigate around the application.*

**link**

*An action used on anchor tags to navigate around the application. You can add an attribute replace to replace the current entry in the history stack instead of adding a new one.*

Despite the description I don't understand the difference, i.e. when would I use which one? Both ways seem to do the trick in letting me navigate within my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They seem to be simply alternatives. There also is a [`links` action](https://github.com/EmilTholin/svelte-routing#links) to affect multiple links at once.

The code documentation of the `link` action states:

```js
/**
 * A link action that can be added to <a href=""> tags rather
 * than using the <Link> component.
 *
```

One undocumented advantage of the `Link` component seems to be that it will set [`aria-current`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-current) automatically:

```html
<a href="{href}" aria-current="{ariaCurrent}" on:click="{onClick}" {...props} {...$$restProps}>
  <slot></slot>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, even though it doesn't seem to make sense to have two options for achieving the same outcome.